# IDIORM INNER_JOIN. How to create query

Tags: sql, inner-join, idiorm

How can I rewrite this using an Idiorm query?

```
SELECT *
FROM regioner_financier_correspond as t1
  INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(t2.id) as maxId
              FROM regioner_financier_correspond as t2
              WHERE `client_code` IN ('03-01', '03-07', '03-08', '03-67')
              GROUP BY t2.client_code) as t3
    ON t1.id=t3.maxId
```

Append:
I try this, but it's doesn't works

```
$data = \ORM::for_table('regioner_financier_correspond')
            ->select('regioner_financier_correspond.*', 't1')
            ->inner_join('regioner_financier_correspond', array('t1.id', '=', 't3.maxId'), 't2')
            ->where_in('client_code', explode(',', $clients))
            ->group_by('t3.client_code')
            ->find_many();
```

Comment: What is an idiom query?

Comment: http://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/querying.html

Comment: @A.Abramov : Idiorm is a lightweight nearly-zero-configuration object-relational mapper and fluent query builder for PHP 5.

Comment: I don't think subqueries are supported by idiorm.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`raw_query`](http://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/querying.html#raw-queries) to get this done, or instead, use the `ORM::raw_execute` function to perform the raw query that you mentioned.